# css conflict with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a live chat service for my website which uses the following code inserted into the header:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
(function() {
    var done = false;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://app.mychat.com/VisitorWidget/WidgetScript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0).appendChild(script);
    script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function(e) {
        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
            var w = new PCWidget({
                c: 'd15cbifh-61bb-49f1-9f98-06d885919a84',
                f: true
            });
            done = true;
        }
    };
})(); 
</script>
```

It is conflicting with one css `div .btn` on my site. I don't want to change all the css and code on my site for this one div, is there a work around, maybe some inline css I can use for the javascript? Thank you.

Comment: could u format the code so its readible?  Also, what error are you receiving?

Comment: surely this is a question you should be asking the chat service support, not Stackoverflow. If they namespace their elements properly then the CSS fix is simple.

Comment: There is no error, the css doesn't look correct is all. Namespacing, yes I figured they were doing something incorrect. I have used other chat services in the past with no conflict. It's great to gain new info!